# How can I display bullet points properly from a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, unicode

So I am getting a string containing a bulleted list and its displaying like this:

blah * blah * blah

when I'd like it to display like:

- blah
- blah
- blah

my thinking is that I would break the string into an array, run through it in a for loop and splice in a new line right before the point. then just return it .toString()

```
var charArry = userInfo.split('');
for (var i = 1; i < charArry.length; i++) {
if (i == '\u2022') 
charArry.splice(i, 0, '\n');
}
return charArry.toString();
```

but maybe that's a terrible approach. any ideas?

Comment: `&bull;` is the special "code" for the bullet.  However, trying to format your html with newlines is inheriently flawed, as at a certain point, the browser will ignore whitespace.  You need to think in terms of how to convert the string to html

Comment: Don't use explicit bullet characters, use `<ul>` and `<li>`

Answer (score 6):

Split the string on "\u2022" and then use `<ul>` to display bullets.

```js
let str = "blah•blah•blah";

let strArr = str.split("\u2022")
```

If you **really** want to add bullets to the string only then you may do something like this:

```js
let newStr = '\u2022' + strArr.join("\n\u2022");
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing things out in text format, create `li` elements and append them to a `ul` element.

```js
let userInfo = 'blah1 blah2 blah3'
var charArry = userInfo.split(' ');
let ul = document.querySelector('#ul')
charArry.forEach(liTxt => {
  let li = document.createElement('li')
  li.innerHTML = liTxt
  ul.appendChild(li)
})
```

```html
<ul id='ul'></ul>
```